# Getting cell value from DataGridView isn't working

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have two `DataGridView`s, one is working well (When I click in the cells, the textbox gets the values), but the second is not working.

Any idea why? I'm using the same code for both.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) 
    form1.TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
    form1.Textbox8.text = DataGridView1.Item(1, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
    form1.Textbox9.text = DataGridView1.Item(2, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
    form1.Textbox10.text = DataGridView1.Item(0, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
    form1.Textbox11.text = DataGridView1.Item(4, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. I can see just code for `DataGridView1`. Also It's not clear what you mean by saying one is *working well* but the second is *not working*. It's not a suitable problem description.

Answer (score 0):

While not DEFINITELY the answer, since its a form level object, I would most likely expect to a handles statement (unless you are dynamically adding the handler elsewhere).  If there's no event handler portion, then this is just a method that isn't getting called:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseClick
    form1.TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
    form1.Textbox8.text = DataGridView1.Item(1, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
    form1.Textbox9.text = DataGridView1.Item(2, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
    form1.Textbox10.text = DataGridView1.Item(0, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
    form1.Textbox11.text = DataGridView1.Item(4, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
End Sub
```